# Html canvas flickering while stroking lines

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
    body{
    margin:0;
    }
    img{
    display:none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="Start()">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<img id="mapImg" src="Img/map.png"/>
<script>
var worker = new Worker("WebWorker.js");

var W = window.innerWidth;
var H = window.innerHeight;

var map = document.getElementById("mapImg");

var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
cvs.width = W;
cvs.height = H;
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

var offscreenCvs = document.createElement("canvas");
offscreenCvs.width = W;
offscreenCvs.height = H;
var offscreenCtx = offscreenCvs.getContext("2d");

var mapCvs = document.createElement("canvas");
var mapCtx,mapData;

var px=25;
var py=0;
var pz=27;
var yaw=0;
var pitch=0;

var buffer=[];

function Start(){
mapCvs.width = map.width;
mapCvs.height = map.height;
mapCtx = mapCvs.getContext("2d");
mapCtx.drawImage(map,0,0);
mapData = mapCtx.getImageData(0,0,map.width,map.height);
worker.postMessage([px,py,pz,yaw,pitch,mapData]);
}
var delta = 0;
var dt = 0;
var Updated=false;
worker.onmessage = function(e){
dt = (performance.now()-delta)/1000;
buffer = e.data;
yaw+= dt*90;
if(!Updated){
requestAnimationFrame(Update);
Updated = true;
}
delta = performance.now();
worker.postMessage([px,py,pz,yaw,pitch,mapData]);
}


function Update(){
offscreenCtx.lineWidth = W/80;
var currentBuffer = buffer;
for(var dists=0; dists<80; dists++){
offscreenCtx.strokeStyle = currentBuffer[dists][0];
offscreenCtx.beginPath();
offscreenCtx.moveTo(W/80*dists,H/2-200/currentBuffer[dists][1]*H);
offscreenCtx.lineTo(W/80*dists,H/2+200/currentBuffer[dists][1]*H);
offscreenCtx.closePath();
offscreenCtx.stroke();
}
//alert(currentBuffer[60][0]);
/*offscreenCtx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
offscreenCtx.beginPath();
offscreenCtx.moveTo(0,0);
offscreenCtx.lineTo(100,100);
offscreenCtx.stroke();*/
ctx.clearRect(0,0,W,H);
ctx.drawImage(offscreenCvs,0,0);
offscreenCtx.clearRect(0,0,W,H);
requestAnimationFrame(Update);
}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make a raycaster with color.
However, when I try to stroke lines, some lines flicker or invisible.
(red flickers,yellow is insivible)

(offscreenCtx.beginPath()
and
offscreenCtx.stroke()
is in for loop in order to change colors.)

here's my web-worker code

```
onmessage=function(e){
    var pkg = e.data;
    postMessage(Raycast(pkg[0],pkg[1],pkg[2],pkg[3],pkg[4],pkg[5]));
    }

    var far = 100;

    function Raycast(x,y,z,yaw,pitch,mapData){
    var distances=[];
    var map = mapData.data;
    for(var rayYaw = yaw-40;rayYaw<yaw+40;rayYaw++){
    for(var l = 0;l<far;l+=1){
    fx = x+Math.round(Math.sin(rayYaw/180*Math.PI)*l);
    fz = z+Math.round(Math.cos(rayYaw/180*Math.PI)*l);
    if(fx<0||fx>mapData.width||fz<0||fz>mapData.height){
    let color = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    distances.unshift([color,Math.min(Math.hypot(fx-x,fz-z),far)*100*Math.cos((rayYaw-yaw)/180*Math.PI)]);
    break;
    }else if(map[Math.round(fx+fz*mapData.width)*4]!=255&&map[Math.round(fx+fz*mapData.width)*4+2]!=255&&map[Math.round(fx+fz*mapData.width)*4+2]!=255){
    let color = "rgb("+map[Math.round(fx+fz*mapData.width)*4]+","+map[Math.round(fx+fz*mapData.width)*4+1]+","+map[Math.round(fx+fz*mapData.width)*4+2]+")";
    distances.unshift([color,Math.min(Math.hypot(fx-x,fz-z),far)*100*Math.cos((rayYaw-yaw)/180*Math.PI)]);
    break;
    }
    }
    }
    return distances;
    }
```

**map.png**
[image: map.png]

Is there anyone who can tell me what's wrong?

Comment: @Kaiido I dont make sense.

Comment: @Kaiido I use buffer variable because I heard rAF syncronizes Updating with gpu

Comment: @Kaiido I dont get "what update flag is never set to false".

Comment: @Kaiido but there is requestAnimationFrame in Update() function. Bottom of it

Comment: I can already see (after reading this time) that you are blowing the memory by copying the whole map's imageData everytime as soon as the worker finished while you could pass it only once, and that clearing your buffer as soon as you drawn it makes the buffer completely useless: you should keep the last drawings on it for as long as the mapData has not been updated, and  make your `Update` function a two forks one: either redraw the paths, either drawImage directly the last state. But none of these points are a clear explanation to what you describe, so there might be more.

Comment: I can give you whole code if you want and that imageData problem, I will fix it soon. thanks for replying

Comment: I have just finished editting post.

I think the problem is in "strokeStyle"

Comment: Your Raycast always outputs `0` when ran ith the *jpeg* map you gave. Also, as I stated in a now deleted comment, it seems your Worker fires far more than once a frame, which will make your memory grow quite fast since you do copy your imageData's buffer everytime.